# Optimal way to store optional additional data on Python

Tags: python, function, performance, data-management

I have a rather easy problem but wish to find an elegant solution that does not come up to mind. Let's say I have a function that takes some arguments and performs calculations:

```
def f(a, b, c):
 # preprocessing of some sort
 d_discarded = ... # initialized and maybe some computations as well
 for i in range(1000):
     d_discarded = ...
     final_value_update = ...
 return final_value_update
```

Up to a user request, I would like to iteratively store and return also the value of d_discarded, but only up to a user request, so not necessarily. How could I envision an efficient way to do so?
A naive solution would be adding if statements and an additional argument like:

```
def f(a, b, c, keep_d = False):
 # preprocessing of some sort
 d_discarded = ... # initialized and maybe some computations as well
 if keep_d:
     l_discarded = []
     l_discarded.append(d_discarded)
 for i in range(1000):
     d_discarded = ...
     final_value_update = ...
     if keep_d:
         l_discarded.append(d_discarded)
 if keep_d:
     return final_value_update, l_discarded
 return final_value_update
```

But this is not efficient, nor elegant, as it calls 1002 times passing an if statement. I surely can do this, but wish to learn a more clever process.
Any consideration is appreciated. I can understand the problem is rather broad but I chose to leave it as it is because it is indeed suitable for any setting.

Comment: I recommend *not* doing this: a function should always return the same type, for clarity. Don't return a two values in one case and one value in another.

Comment: Move the logic outside your function: *always* return `final_value_update, l_discarded`, then use the second return value if requested.

Comment: If the function is called only a thousand times, the performance impact of the "if"s or of the better solution by 9769953 can be neglected. Regarding performance in general you should better measure than guess from code.

Comment: well, thanks everyone. Yes, @MichaelButscher I know I should measure, but in terms of lines of code my solution would definitely be more annoying to type even ignoring that.

Comment: @9769953 what if however I would store information that is actually not needed most of the times? If i needed that discarded list only once every 3 years, would it still be reasonable to do so?

Comment: If once every 3 years, I wouldn't include this option *at all*. When such a user comes along, I'd say "sorry, that is not an option" or "we'll have to provide custom code, for xyz amount of costs" (as you seem to be measuring in amounts of lines of code, given your above comment).

Comment: In this case you can use your original code (second variant in the question) and change the last line to `return final_value_update, None`. So the basic return type is always the same.